# Geodesic equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields, covariance

I have a technical question about the geodesic equation.

Assume we have a frame $(E_{1},E_{2},E_{3},E_{4})$ (not necessarily a coordinate frame). Assume we have a parametrized curve $\gamma(s)\in M$ with the tangent vector $v\in T_{\gamma(s)}M$. Then if I want to write down the geodesic equation $\nabla_{v}v=\nabla_{v^{a}E_{a}}V^{b}E_{b}=0$ in this frame I get a term (among others) which looks like

\begin{equation*}
v^{b}E_{b}(v^{a})E_{a}
\end{equation*}

How exactly can I understand the $v^{b}E_{b}(v^{a})$ part? The $v^{a}=v^{a}(s)$ and $E_{b}$ acts by taking partial derivatives with respect to *coordinates*. So how exactly does the frame act on it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. $E_b$ is a vector field and $v^a$ is a function, so $E_b(v^a)$ is the directional derivative as usual.

Comment: @MBN what I meant was, if I write it down explicitly I have: $E_{b}(v^{a})=(E_{b}^{(1)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}+…+E_{b}^{(4)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{4}})(v^{a}(\gamma(s)))$. As it stands now, I don't understand how I take a partial derivative w.r.t $x_{i}$ of $v^{a}(\gamma(s))$

Answer (score 1):

We have the frame $\{e_\mu\}_{\mu=0,\dotsc,3}$ in terms of which the velocity vector is $v=v^\mu e_\mu$. There are a few properties of the affine connection which I would like to summarize:

> $$\nabla_{fX}Y=f\nabla_XY$$
>   $$\nabla_X(fY)=f\nabla_XY+X(f)Y$$
>   $$\nabla_{e_\mu}e_\nu=\Gamma^\lambda{}_{\mu\nu}e_\lambda$$

Using this, let's get to work. We have
$$0=\nabla_vv=\nabla_{v^\mu e_\mu}(v^\nu e_\nu)=v^\mu\big[e_\mu(v^\nu)e_\nu+\Gamma^\lambda{}_{\mu\nu}v^\nu e_\lambda\big]$$
Changing some indices and removing the frame, we have
$$v^\mu e_\mu(v^\nu)+\Gamma^\nu{}_{\mu\lambda}v^\mu v^\lambda=0$$
The first term is simply the acceleration:
$$v^\mu e_\mu v^\nu=\frac{dv^\nu}{d\tau}$$
I hope that clears things up.

Comment: thank you, but I was rather asking what is $v^{\mu}e_{\mu}(v^{\nu})$ written out in terms of $\gamma(s)$. I agree with the acceleration expression, but there $\frac{d}{d\tau}$ is a symbol. @ 0celo7

Comment: @user46446 Perhaps it's $$\frac{v^\mu(\gamma(s))}{ds}$$

Comment: @0celo7, Could you tell me what means $e_\mu(\nu^{\mu})$? I am rather a newbie

Comment: @Stefano It is the vector $e_\mu$ applied to the function $v^\nu$.